# How to open include files in Komodo editor

Tags: php, komodo

i m using `Komodo Version 6.0.3`  for PHP coding .  i want to know some functionality in Komodo editor

- How to  open included files ( php ) just  like dream weaver ( by Pressing CTRL+D ).
- How to comment HTML style  ?? like `<!-- HTML code -->`
- How to see the code and design preview???

if it is possible then tell me .

Thanks A Lot

Comment: Shouldn't this go on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @oktosite Doesn't need to. It's software use related. They sometimes even send programming editor questions our way.

Answer (score 0):

> How to open included files ( php ) just like dream weaver

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd> ([Create a Project](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/prefs.html#projects) beforehand)

> How to comment HTML style ?? like `<!-- HTML code -->`

<kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd>

> How to see the code and design preview???

<kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+V</kbd>

**References**

[Komodo 6 Windows/Linux Key Bindings](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/defkeybind.html)